# How to stop parent component css not to overwrite child component css (Angular 5)?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using `<mat-select>` in my navigation bar which is being used in different pages.
I am also using `<mat-select>` in one of my forms where it has a drop down.
I noticed that when I use `::ng-deep`, it overwrite the `<mat-select>` CSS in the other component as well. I have also tried encapsulation, but that doesn't work.

Nav-Bar

```
::ng-deep .mat-select-panel {
  margin-left: -22.75rem;
  margin-top: 2.875rem;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```
<mat-select formControlName="state">
    <mat-option  class="my-component" *ngFor="let city of cities"[value]="city.abbrev">{{ city.abbrev }}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

This overwrites any other components that is using `<mat-select>`, since the component NAV-BAR is being used throughout the entire app. How can I just use it for navigation bar, and not let it overwrite other components?

Comment: have you tried putting a custom class on your `<mat-select>` ?

Comment: @SmokeyDawson wont help, panel is rendered outside of mat select

Comment: Have a look into panelClass https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#adding-custom-styles-to-the-dropdown-panel. Could be possible to do with creating wrapper component and adding encaplsulation none

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to use [panelClass](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#adding-custom-styles-to-the-dropdown-panel)

So you can make wrapper component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'wrapper',
  template: '<ng-content></ng-content>',
  styles: [`.make-it-green-again {
    background: green;
  }`],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class WrapperExample {
  @ContentChild(MatSelect, {static: false})
  element: MatSelect;

    ngAfterContentInit() {
    if(this.element){
      this.element.panelClass = 'make-it-green-again'
    }
  }
}
```

then in you html

```
  <wrapper>
    <mat-select>
      <mat-option>None</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="option2">Option 2</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="option3">Option 4</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </wrapper>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-select  >
    <mat-option>None</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option2">Option 2</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option3">Option 4</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
```

Comment: yes maybe I would have to create new component, even though I don't want to.

Comment: @PaulSartre thanks for nice question :) I have updated my answer

Comment: So I tried a different method which was easier. Use another library in different components instead of making a new component.

Answer (score 0):

append `!important` to the CSSs in your innermost component

eg.

```
.mat-select-panel {
    height: 100vh!important;
}
```